# A polynomial function that is non-constant is injective iff it contains one root that is non-zero, or no roots at all.

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots

I was messing around the other day in desmos, and I began to graph functions which have certain roots, (for instance $x^2-x-1$), and noticed that these functions are not injective. In this case, $\phi$ and $\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$, are both $0$ once plugged into this function. So I started thinking, is this true generally? And I came up with this claim:

Claim: A polynomial function that is not constant is injective iff it contains one root that is non-zero (such as $\phi\neq 0$), or has no roots at all.

I do not yet have a proof, but I am working on it. Would this claim be correct? If not, provide a counterexample please. :)

Comment: No.  This claim is incorrect.  Consider $(x+1)^2$ and $x^2+1$ respectively as counterexamples.

Comment: $x^3-x-1$ is not injective, has a unique real root, and that root is not zero.

Comment: Now... it is true that if $f(x)$ is injective then $f(x)$ has at most one root... this has nothing to do with polynomials and follows trivially from the definition of injectivity and roots.  The reverse implication is false as previously mentioned.

Comment: $x^3$ is another counterexample since its root is $0$ (and it is injective).

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(EDITED)
A nonconstant polynomial with real coefficients is injective on the real numbers  if its **derivative** has no real roots.

A polynomial with no real roots can never be injective on the real numbers.

Comment: $x^3$ is injective even though its derivative has a real root. -- I'd say, we need the derivative to have no real root of odd order